# Deterministic random number generation across systems

Tags: c#, random, random-seed

I need to send an identical sequence of random numbers to a distributed network of applications.

Since such sequence might be quite long, I was thinking about sending just a (randomly generated) centralized seed initialization number and the length of the desired sequence.

Given that every component on the receiving hand will use the same .NET version, would that be a viable solution to have identical random data generated on all of my nodes?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17094189/crossplatform-random-number-generator

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Would you care to write this as an answer so that I can mark as accepted?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to distribute a seed for Random(int seed) and recreate the same sequence assuming that you are using the same version of .NET in all environments.

[Remarks on System.Random @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx)

> **Notes to Callers** The implementation of the random number generator in
>   the Random class is not guaranteed to remain the same across major
>   versions of the .NET Framework. As a result, your application code
>   should not assume that the same seed will result in the same
>   pseudo-random sequence in different versions of the .NET Framework.

If you can see a case where the framework version will change, or if you may need to recreate an old sequence after you've started using a new version, you'll want to create your own random implementation.

See the answers of this question for pointers: [Crossplatform random number generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17094189/crossplatform-random-number-generator)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Random`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctssatww.aspx) class with a seed or use a service oriented architecture.

`Random` when initialized with a seed will produce an identical sequence.

Comment: There's a major caveat to this which has been discussed on SO before. See drch's answer.