# Deterministic OpenSimplexNoise across Godot versions

Tags: random, multiplayer, godot, perlin-noise, gdscript

For a given version of Godot, you can deterministically generate `OpenSimplexNoise` using `seed` ([documentation](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_opensimplexnoise.html)).

However, in the [documentation](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_randomnumbergenerator.html) for `RandomNumberGenerator` there is the following:

> Note: The underlying algorithm is an implementation detail. As a
> result, it should not be depended upon for reproducible random streams
> across Godot versions.

Some workarounds for the above issue are described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17094189/crossplatform-random-number-generator), the short answer is to write a custom portable RNG.

Is there any way to insert a custom RNG for `OpenSimplexNoise` to manage determinism?  Is there another solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Godot developers are warning you that they might decide to change `RandomNumberGenerator` for a future version (also and some changes happened already).

And no, you can't insert a custom random number generator for `OpenSimplexNoise`.

Anyway, `OpenSimplexNoise` does not use `RandomNumberGenerator` or `rand`. Instead it takes this library as a git module: [smcameron/open-simplex-noise-in-c](https://github.com/smcameron/open-simplex-noise-in-c).

Does `OpenSimplexNoise` change? Rarely. However, there is a breaking change in `OpenSimplexNoise` for Godot 4 and 3.4: the axis has been swaped (this is a fix).

---

So that leads us to add a custom noise solution. Which could be a port of OpenSimplex noise to C# or GDScript.

See [open-simplex-noise.c from Godot source](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/master/thirdparty/misc/open-simplex-noise.c) and [digitalshadow/OpenSimplexNoise.cs](https://gist.github.com/digitalshadow/134a3a02b67cecd72181) (which is a port to C#, there are some other ports linked in the comments there too).

---

And for the texture, there are a couple options:

- You can create a script that draws the image (I suggest using lockbits) and set it.
- Or you can extend Viewport (which entains adding a Viewport to the scene and attaching a script). Then you take advantage of `ViewportTexture`, and you can take advantage of shaders to create the texture you want. Take [BastiaanOlij/godot-noise-texture-asset](https://github.com/BastiaanOlij/godot-noise-texture-asset) for reference.

Comment: Looking at the library it uses, it’s based on a linear congruential generator written in C.  I think this guarantees determinism and portability so long as I am using this library. For me, I think this means I can use it and not worry, unless that implementation changes and I need to upgrade godot version for some reason.  In that case, I could probably invoke the library directly myself